# Running postgres command in pod definition doesnt work

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I'm just adding the containers part of the spec. Everything is otherwise set up and working fine and values are hardcoded here. This is a simple Postgres pod that is part of a single replica deployment with its own PVC to persist state. But the problem is having nothing to do with my pod/deployment setup.

```
containers:
    - name: postgres-container
      image: postgres
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-internal-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          subPath: postgres
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: postgres-internal-cnf
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      command: ['psql']
      args: [-U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'dominion'" | grep -q 1 || psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE dominion"]
```

This command will create a database if it does not already exist. If I create the deployment and exec into the pod and run this command everything works fine. If I however run it here the pod fails to spin up and I get this error:

psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I was under the impression that this error comes from the default connection values being incorrect, but here I am hardcoding the localhost and the port number.

Answer (score 2):

With your pod spec, you've replaced the default command -- which starts up the postgres server -- with your own command, so the server never starts. The proper way to perform initialization tasks with the official Postgres image is [in the documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts).

You want to move your initialization commands into a ConfigMap, and then mount the scripts into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as described in those docs.

The docs have more details, but here's a short example. We want to run
`CREATE DATABASE dominion` when the postgres server starts (and only
if it is starting with an empty data directory). We can define a
simple SQL script in a `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-init-scripts
data:
  create-dominion-db.sql: |
    CREATE DATABASE dominion
```

And then mount that script into the appropriate location in the pod
spec:

```
volumes:
  - name: postgres-init-scripts
    configMap:
      name: postgres-init-scripts
containers:
  - name: postgres-container
    image: postgres
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
      - name: postgres-internal-volume
        mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
        subPath: postgres
      - name: postgres-init-scripts
        mountPath:
        /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-dominion-db.sql
        subPath: create-dominion-db.sql
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: postgres-internal-cnf
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5432
```

Comment: Thankyou! this is really helpful.

Comment: This is not missing a `configMapRef`. I had originally neglected to remove your `command` and `args` config, which I have corrected, and this should now run as written. I've put together a deployable example at <https://github.com/larsks/so-example-69283138>.